# Define parameters in Jenkins Auxiliary template

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline template that has an attribute called "testJobs". The idea is to allow the implementing job to perform its build and then trigger a list of downstream jobs to perform validation.

My biggest problem with this is I cannot figure out how to pass along parameters from the calling pipeline.

For example, my pipeline has a build parameter which defines the git branch to pull. When iterating through the post-build "testJobs" I want to pass that branch along as a parameter, **if** that is a parameter on the downstream job.

Is there a way to define the parameters using variables within the auxiliary template?